# How do I close an answer?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Sometimes I flag an answer because it is irrelevant or it is spam. But when I check my `helpful flag` stats, it is marked as rejected with a comment to Close it instead.

I have 12K rep, but I don't see a Close function here:

[image]

Comment: I don't see flags on that post in your history.

Comment: @MatthewRead Not on that post, but on previous posts that I flagged for spam.

Comment: @MatthewRead See my flags for `Installing TWRP over CWM` or `Keep a careful watch for roof damage`.

Comment: According to rejected flag notes, you should be flagging it as spam instead of flagging it with a comment. Flagging it as spam will auto-delete the post after enough people have flagged it as spam without moderator intervention.

Comment: Those flags show you used a custom reason of "spam spam spam" instead of a built-in spam flag, and the response was to use the spam flag.  Are you seeing something else?

Comment: @MatthewRead Not sure why I didn't see it before, but I have seen the `it is spam` item now.

Answer (score 3):

In `flag`, there is an `it is spam` item.